# jQuery disable option when true

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Hi I'm trying to create a simple quiz.  I'm new to jQuery so apologies if it looks daft.

But it's not working.  If the user selects q1b...the correct answer...jQuery will disable the remaining radio buttons.

html form:

```
           <div class="quiz">
                     <ul class="no-bullet" id="question1">
                        <li><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1a"> <label for="q1a">Incorrect</label></li>
                        <li class="answer"><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1b"> <label for="q1b">Correct</label></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1c"> <label for="q1c">Incorrect</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//If user selects q1b  which is the correct answer...
//all other radio buttons will be disabled

$('#question1').click(function() {
   if($('#q1b').is(':checked'))

       { 
       //disables radio button q1a and radio button q1c
          $("input[type='radio' id="q1a" && "q1c").removeAttr("disabled"); 

       }
     });

 });
```

Comment: you  are removing disabe attribute: must use `$('input[type='radio' id="q1a" && "q1c")').prop('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this : register click event handler for `.answer` radio button and inside it disable all other sibling radio button using `.prop()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //If user selects q1b  which is the correct answer...
  //all other radio buttons will be disabled

  $('li.answer input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
     //disable all other radio button

 $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type="radio"]').not(this).prop('disabled',true);
 });
});
```

Comment: Works perfect.  Thanks

It seems quite random.  Is using specific identifiers not necessary?

Comment: yeah it is good practice to use specific identities but make sure that ids must be unique through out the DOM. I have posted code that will work for all such radio button having same structure like if you have multiple such questions then same code will do for all. Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.answer input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
     $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type="radio"]').not(this).attr('disabled',true);
     });
    });
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="quiz">
                         <ul class="no-bullet" id="question1">
                            <li><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1a"> <label for="q1a">Incorrect</label></li>
                            <li class="answer"><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1b"> <label for="q1b">Correct</label></li>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1c"> <label for="q1c">Incorrect</label></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```